# RSYNC Style Mirror Folder Application

Tags: c#, file-system, console

I've written a mirror folder application in C#. It uses [CommandLine](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjCj7uYnLLPAhVQxCYKHWJ2DU8QFggvMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcommandline.codeplex.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNFjbTQDYs6LUK2N8naC8bHBPSnLJQ&sig2=eHaDa9v6H5ES3wvJIq-n2w) for command line parsing. I'm just looking for a general review.

```
using CommandLine;
using CommandLine.Text;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace mirror_dir {

internal class Program {
    private static bool service_mode = false;
    private static int copied_directories = 0;
    private static int copied_files = 0;
    private static int current_file_count = 0;
    private static int current_folder_count = 0;
    private static int deleted_directories = 0;
    private static int deleted_files = 0;
    private static int failed_copied_files = 0;
    private static int failed_deleted_files = 0;
    private static int failed_directory_copies = 0;
    private static int failed_directory_deletes = 0;
    private static int failed_updated_files = 0;
    private static int total_file_count = 0;
    private static int total_folder_count = 0;
    private static int updated_files = 0;
    private static List<String> excluded_paths = new List<String>();
    private static List<String> log_entries = new List<String>();
    private static String log_file = @".\log.txt";
    private static Timer commit_log;
    private static Timer progress_report;

    private static void check_paths(Options options) {
        if (!Directory.Exists(options.InputFolder)) {
            Console.WriteLine(options.InputFolder + " not found!");
            unmount_drives(options);
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
        if (!Directory.Exists(options.OutputFolder)) {
            try {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(options.OutputFolder);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Console.WriteLine("[Error] Problem with destination path: " + options.OutputFolder + " " + e.Message);
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }
        if (!Directory.Exists(new FileInfo(options.LogFile).Directory.ToString())) {
            try {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(new FileInfo(options.LogFile).Directory.ToString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Console.WriteLine("[Error] Log file doesn't exist and it couldn't be created. " + e.Message);
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }
        if (!File.Exists(options.LogFile)) {
            FileStream f = File.Create(options.LogFile);
            f.Close();
        }
    }

    private static void copy_structure(String from_path, String to_path) {
        from_path = Path.GetFullPath(from_path);
        to_path = Path.GetFullPath(to_path);

        if (!excluded_paths.Contains(from_path)) {
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(from_path);
            Parallel.ForEach(dir.GetDirectories(), (d) => {
                current_folder_count++;
                String d_to = d.FullName.Replace(from_path, to_path);

                if (!Directory.Exists(d_to)) {
                    try {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(d_to);
                        log("Created Directory: " + d_to);
                        copied_directories++;
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        log(ex.Message);
                        failed_directory_copies++;
                    }
                }
                copy_structure(d.FullName, d_to);

                Directory.SetCreationTime(d_to, d.CreationTime);
                Directory.SetLastAccessTime(d_to, d.LastAccessTime);
                Directory.SetLastWriteTime(d_to, d.LastWriteTime);
            });
            Parallel.ForEach(dir.GetFiles(), (f) => {
                current_file_count++;
                String f_to = f.FullName.Replace(from_path, to_path);

                if (!File.Exists(f_to)) {
                    try {
                        File.Copy(f.FullName, f_to);
                        File.SetAttributes(f_to, f.Attributes);
                        log("Copied File: " + f_to);
                        copied_files++;
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        log(ex.Message);
                        failed_copied_files++;
                    }
                } else {
                    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(f_to);
                    if (f.LastWriteTime > fi.LastWriteTime) {
                        try {
                            File.Copy(f.FullName, f_to, true);
                            File.SetAttributes(f_to, f.Attributes);
                            log("Updated File: " + f_to);
                            updated_files++;
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            log(ex.Message);
                            failed_updated_files++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private static void get_counts(String from_path) {
        from_path = Path.GetFullPath(from_path);
        if (!excluded_paths.Contains(from_path)) {
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(from_path);
            Parallel.ForEach(dir.GetDirectories(), (d) => {
                total_folder_count++;
                get_counts(d.FullName);
            });
            Parallel.ForEach(dir.GetFiles(), (f) => {
                total_file_count++;
            });
        }
    }

    private static void get_excluded_path_list(Options options) {
        if (options.excluded_paths != null && options.excluded_paths.Count > 0) {
            foreach (String path in options.excluded_paths) {
                excluded_paths.Add(Path.GetFullPath(path));
            }
        }
    }

    private static void log(String output) {
        lock (log_entries) {
            log_entries.Add(output);
        }
    }

    private static void log_commit(Object o) {
        lock (log_entries) {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(File.Open(log_file, FileMode.Append))) {
                foreach (string output in log_entries) {
                    sw.WriteLine("[" + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + "] " + output);
                }
                log_entries.Clear();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args) {
        CommandLine.Parser clp = new CommandLine.Parser();
        Options options = new Options();
        clp.ParseArguments(args, options);
        service_mode = options.service_mode;

        if (!service_mode) Console.Clear();
        if (options.InputFolder == null || options.OutputFolder == null || options.LogFile == null) {
            Console.WriteLine(options.GetUsage());
        } else {
            log_file = Path.GetFullPath(options.LogFile);
            mount_drives(options);
            check_paths(options);
            get_excluded_path_list(options);
            get_counts(options.InputFolder);

            commit_log = new Timer(log_commit, null, 0, 2000);
            progress_report = new Timer(report_progress, null, 0, 1000);

            reset_traversal_count();
            copy_structure(options.InputFolder, options.OutputFolder);

            if (options.delete_flag) {
                reset_traversal_count();
                remove_missing(options.InputFolder, options.OutputFolder);
            }

            unmount_drives(options);
            log_commit(null);
        }
    }

    private static void mount_drives(Options options) {
        if (options.MountSource != null) {
            Console.WriteLine("Mounting " + options.InputFolder + " to " + options.MountSource);
            Process p1 = new Process();
            p1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            p1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p1.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";

            if (options.sm_username != null) {
                p1.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c net use " + options.MountSource + " \"" + options.InputFolder + "\" " + "/user:" + options.sm_username + " " + options.sm_password;
            } else {
                p1.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c net use " + options.MountSource + " \"" + options.InputFolder + "\"";
            }

            p1.Start();
            p1.WaitForExit();

            if (!Directory.Exists(options.MountSource)) {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to mount " + options.InputFolder + " to " + options.MountSource);
                Console.WriteLine(p1.StandardError.ReadToEnd());

                Environment.Exit(0);
            }

            options.InputFolder = options.MountSource;
        }
        if (options.MountDest != null) {
            Console.WriteLine("Mounting " + options.OutputFolder + " to " + options.MountDest);
            Process p2 = new Process();
            p2.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            p2.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p2.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";

            if (options.dm_username != null) {
                p2.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c net use " + options.MountDest + " \"" + options.OutputFolder + "\" " + "/user:" + options.dm_username + " " + options.dm_password;
            } else {
                p2.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c net use " + options.MountDest + " \"" + options.OutputFolder + "\"";
            }

            p2.Start();
            p2.WaitForExit();

            if (!Directory.Exists(options.MountDest)) {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to mount " + options.OutputFolder + " to " + options.MountDest);
                Console.WriteLine(p2.StandardError.ReadToEnd());
                unmount_drives(options);
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }

            options.OutputFolder = options.MountDest;
        }
    }

    private static void remove_missing(String from_path, String to_path) {
        from_path = Path.GetFullPath(from_path);
        to_path = Path.GetFullPath(to_path);

        if (!excluded_paths.Contains(from_path)) {
            if (Directory.Exists(to_path)) {
                DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(to_path);

                Parallel.ForEach(dir.GetDirectories(), (d) => {
                    current_folder_count++;
                    String d_from = d.FullName.Replace(to_path, from_path);

                    if (!Directory.Exists(d_from)) {
                        try {
                            Directory.Delete(d.FullName, true);
                            log("Removed Directory: " + d.FullName);
                            deleted_directories++;
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            log(ex.Message);
                            failed_directory_deletes++;
                        }
                    } else {
                        remove_missing(d_from, d.FullName);
                    }
                });
                Parallel.ForEach(dir.GetFiles(), (f) => {
                    current_file_count++;
                    String f_from = f.FullName.Replace(to_path, from_path);

                    if (!File.Exists(f_from)) {
                        try {
                            File.Delete(f.FullName);
                            log("Removed File: " + f.FullName);
                            deleted_files++;
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            log(ex.Message);
                            failed_deleted_files++;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    private static void report_progress(Object o) {
        if (!service_mode) {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Scanned Directories " + current_folder_count + "/" + total_folder_count);
            Console.WriteLine("Scanned Files " + current_file_count + "/" + total_file_count);
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Copied Directories: " + copied_directories);
            Console.WriteLine("Removed Directories: " + deleted_directories);
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Copied Files: " + copied_files);
            Console.WriteLine("Updated Files: " + updated_files);
            Console.WriteLine("Removed Files: " + deleted_files);
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Failed Directory Copies: " + failed_directory_copies);
            Console.WriteLine("Failed Directory Deletes: " + failed_directory_deletes);
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Failed File Copies: " + failed_copied_files);
            Console.WriteLine("Failed File Updates: " + failed_updated_files);
            Console.WriteLine("Failed File Deletes: " + failed_deleted_files);
        }
    }

    private static void reset_traversal_count() {
        current_file_count = 0;
        current_folder_count = 0;
    }
    private static void unmount_drives(Options options) {
        Process p3 = new Process();
        p3.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        p3.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p3.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p3.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";

        if (options.MountSource != null) {
            Console.WriteLine("Unmounting " + options.MountSource);
            p3.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c net use " + options.MountSource + " /delete /yes";
            p3.Start();
            p3.WaitForExit();
        }
        if (options.MountDest != null) {
            Console.WriteLine("Unmounting " + options.MountDest);
            p3.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c net use " + options.MountSource + " /delete /yes";
            p3.Start();
            p3.WaitForExit();
        }
    }

    private class Options {

        [Option("delete", Required = false,
          HelpText = "Delete files that are not in the source directory.")]
        public bool delete_flag { get; set; }

        [Option("dest_mount_password", DefaultValue = null,
          HelpText = "Password to be used for mounting the destination path.")]
        public String dm_password { get; set; }

        [Option("dest_mount_username", DefaultValue = null,
          HelpText = "Username to be used for mounting the destination path.")]
        public String dm_username { get; set; }

        [OptionList("exclude", Separator = ';', HelpText = "Excluded paths seperated by ; {Must be fully qualified paths or relative to executable}")]
        public List<string> excluded_paths { get; set; }

        [Option('s', "source_folder", DefaultValue = null,
          HelpText = "Source Folder")]
        public String InputFolder { get; set; }

        [Option('l', "log_file", DefaultValue = null,
          HelpText = "Log File")]
        public String LogFile { get; set; }

        [Option("dest_mount", DefaultValue = null,
          HelpText = "Path to mount the destination directory. If you do not want to mount this directory then don't pass this argument.")]
        public String MountDest { get; set; }

        [Option("source_mount", DefaultValue = null,
          HelpText = "Path to mount the source directory. If you do not want to mount this directory then don't pass this argument.")]
        public String MountSource { get; set; }

        [Option('d', "destination_folder", DefaultValue = null,
          HelpText = "Destination Folder")]
        public String OutputFolder { get; set; }

        [Option("service_mode", Required = false,
          HelpText = "This flag must be enabled when redirecting console output to a text file.")]
        public bool service_mode { get; set; }

        [Option("source_mount_password", DefaultValue = null,
          HelpText = "Password to be used for mounting the source path.")]
        public String sm_password { get; set; }

        [Option("source_mount_username", DefaultValue = null,
          HelpText = "Username to be used for mounting the source path.")]
        public String sm_username { get; set; }
        [HelpOption]
        public string GetUsage() {
            return HelpText.AutoBuild(this,
              (HelpText current) => HelpText.DefaultParsingErrorsHandler(this, current));
        }
    }
}
}
```